# Python code called through pipe in C, does not work, and throws errors

Tags: python, c, python-2.7, pipe

I am new to Python. I am writing a software using C. For plotting some graphs, and a few other tasks, I am opening pipe to Python and running a `.py` python file.
Like this:

```
FILE* py = popen ("C:/Python27/python.exe", "w");
system(myPythonFile.py -d SomeDirectory);
```

OS: Windows10 64-bit
I have multiple versions installed: Python27, Python37, Python39.
In  the:

1. Environment variables Path: I have only included path to `C:\Python27`, `C:\Python27\Scripts` and `C:\Python27\python.exe`
2. System variables path: I have included the same paths to `C:\Python27`, `C:\Python27\Scripts` and `C:\Python27\python.exe`
   (I have removed the path to other versions of Python Installations)
3. In PYTHONPATH: `C:\Python27`,`C:\Python27\Lib` and `C:\Python27\DLLs`.

I am having some trouble here. Everytime I run this, it gives me this error. I am unable to figure out what's exactly going wrong. I have referred to multiple QnA s, websites, but to no avail. I even tried uninstalling and reinstalling some packages.

This was actually working perfectly okay until yesterday. Yesterday I uninstalled and reinstalled GDAL package, added some environment variables for the same, and slowly the below-written error started popping up.

```
 File "C:\Python37\Lib\site.py", line 177
    file=sys.stderr)
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
Error processing line 1 of C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\matplotlib-3.4.3-py3.9-nspkg.pth:

  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Python37\Lib\site.py", line 168, in addpackage
      exec(line)
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "C:\Python37\Lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 51, in <module>
      _w_long = _bootstrap_external._w_long
  AttributeError: module 'importlib._bootstrap_external' has no attribute '_w_long'

Remainder of file ignored
Error processing line 1 of C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\sphinxcontrib_applehelp-1.0.2-py3.8-nspkg.pth:

  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Python37\Lib\site.py", line 168, in addpackage
      exec(line)
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "C:\Python37\Lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 51, in <module>
      _w_long = _bootstrap_external._w_long
  AttributeError: module 'importlib._bootstrap_external' has no attribute '_w_long'

Remainder of file ignored
Error processing line 1 of C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\sphinxcontrib_devhelp-1.0.2-py3.8-nspkg.pth:

  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Python37\Lib\site.py", line 168, in addpackage
      exec(line)
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "C:\Python37\Lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 51, in <module>
      _w_long = _bootstrap_external._w_long
  AttributeError: module 'importlib._bootstrap_external' has no attribute '_w_long'

Remainder of file ignored
Error processing line 1 of C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\sphinxcontrib_htmlhelp-2.0.0-py3.9-nspkg.pth:

  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Python37\Lib\site.py", line 168, in addpackage
      exec(line)
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "C:\Python37\Lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 51, in <module>
      _w_long = _bootstrap_external._w_long
  AttributeError: module 'importlib._bootstrap_external' has no attribute '_w_long'

Remainder of file ignored
Error processing line 1 of C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\sphinxcontrib_jsmath-1.0.1-py3.7-nspkg.pth:

  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Python37\Lib\site.py", line 168, in addpackage
      exec(line)
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "C:\Python37\Lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 51, in <module>
      _w_long = _bootstrap_external._w_long
  AttributeError: module 'importlib._bootstrap_external' has no attribute '_w_long'

Remainder of file ignored
Error processing line 1 of C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\sphinxcontrib_qthelp-1.0.3-py3.8-nspkg.pth:

  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Python37\Lib\site.py", line 168, in addpackage
      exec(line)
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "C:\Python37\Lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 51, in <module>
      _w_long = _bootstrap_external._w_long
  AttributeError: module 'importlib._bootstrap_external' has no attribute '_w_long'

Remainder of file ignored
Error processing line 1 of C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\sphinxcontrib_serializinghtml-1.1.5-py3.9-nspkg.pth:

  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Python37\Lib\site.py", line 168, in addpackage
      exec(line)
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "C:\Python37\Lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 51, in <module>
      _w_long = _bootstrap_external._w_long
  AttributeError: module 'importlib._bootstrap_external' has no attribute '_w_long'

Remainder of file ignored
Error processing line 1 of C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\zope.interface-5.4.0-py3.9-nspkg.pth:

  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Python37\Lib\site.py", line 168, in addpackage
      exec(line)
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "C:\Python37\Lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 51, in <module>
      _w_long = _bootstrap_external._w_long
  AttributeError: module 'importlib._bootstrap_external' has no attribute '_w_long'

Remainder of file ignored
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\supriya\pplot.py", line 1, in <module>
    import numpy as np
  File "C:\Users\user11\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 127, in <module>
    from numpy.__config__ import show as show_config
  File "C:\Users\user11\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\numpy\__config__.py", line 13, in <module>
    os.add_dll_directory(extra_dll_dir)
AttributeError: module 'os' has no attribute 'add_dll_directory'
```

Comment: The C statements you show is invalid and not how you Python or a Python script.

Comment: Did you restart your computer after setting all the environment variables? Also, are you sure all your paths include Python**2**7 instead of Python**3**7?

Comment: You're showing your setup uses Python 2.7, but the error trace shows Python 3.7. You may need to start debugging your installation.

Comment: @MattDMo Yes, I restarted the computer after setting Environment variables. Also, I rechecked, There is no path to other Python versions in the Environment variables

Comment: @9769953 Sorry for my ignorance, but how exactly do I debug the installation? Actually, these versions were installed by someone else before me.

Comment: Debugging in the general sense: you set paths for Python 2.7, but you end up with a backtrace for Python 3.7. We can't tell how, as there is not enough information.

Comment: Please note the comment about your non-syntactical C statements: the second one should take a string (which it now doesn't), and the first one appears to open a Python 2.7 shell in interactive mode (which would require you to put streamdata/characters to the pipe, before closing it).

Comment: *If* the C statements actually execute, there is every chance `myPythonFile.py` just runs with Python 3.7, especially if that is given in the hashbang on the first line of the program.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all your inputs.  Actually something different solved the issue. I Deleted the PYTHONPATH variable, rebooted my PC and the program started working perfectly fine. I don't understand. Why did this happen? Was it confused about choosing a path to any version, or could it be something else?